# jQuery won't count up variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem with my jQuery script: instead of counting up all variables, the script puts them next to each other. How do I count up the variables? (I am new to jQuery, so maybe I overlooked something or made a stupid mistake).

This is the line of code that should count up the variables.

```
totalcost = ((commissioncost + paypalcost) + qrticketcost);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bsuh5q8k/1/

Thanks.

Comment: Code you posted is not jQuery, it is JavaScrip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often when you retrieve a value from a field using jquery's .val(), you'll get the string value (String type) instead of the numeric value you desire here. For instance, the field value may be 37.50, but you're getting "37.50" from .val()

So when you do this:

```
commissioncost = $('input[name=price]').val();
```

You'll get the String value.

So instead, try this:

```
commissioncost = Number($('input[name=price]').val());
```

This will convert/cast the value into a Number for you.

Also, a word of caution: just be sure whatever value is in that field, it can be evaluated as a Number, otherwise `comissioncost` will equal `"NaN"` (not a number) and will give you the same grief you're experiencing now.  The rudimentary method to check if the type conversion was successful is:

```
commissioncost = Number($('input[name=price]').val());
if(isNaN(commissioncost)){
    // oops, value wasn't a number!
}else{
    // hooray! value was a number (most of the time - but that's a longer discussion)
}
```

Comment: When retrieving a value using *either* the `value` property, or jQuery's `val()` method, you will always get a string; although to get a number there is the `valueAsNumber` property which will return a number ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/20tmb2ow/)), or NaN ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/20tmb2ow/1)) (tested in Firefox and Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

`commissioncost` is being treated as a string.  So when you add it thinks you're wanting to concatenate.

When you pull it from the input, explicitly tell Javascript that it's a number/float.

`commissioncost = parseFloat($('input[name=price]').val());`